# How Can I Set Object Metadata in Google Cloud Storage With Rails' ActiveStorage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rails-activestorage

For instance I see that Google Cloud Storage allows me to set the following metadata on an object:

[image: Google Cloud Storage metadata screenshot]

(The default fields are):

```
Content-Type
Content-Encoding
Content-Disposition
Content-Language
Cache-Control
```

Does Rails' ActiveStorage GCSService (as of 5.2.0) provide any interface for this?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: GCS also lets one set custom metadata key/value pairs which is what i'd be interested in setting.